# What is the max array length that can be assigned AutoCompleteTextview?

Tags: android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I am trying to assign an array with length more than 100000 to AutoCompleteTextview. But when i run the suggestions are not showing up, if i reduce the number of items, then the suggestions are showed. I was wondering whether there is a limit to the array that can be assigned to AutoCompleteTextview. Can any one help on this. Thank you.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833245/android-autocompletetextview-dropdown-question

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the same issue. I will try those suggestion.

Comment: The link you provided was helpful. The reason the autocomplete wasn't  working beacuse of NULL element in the array. i corrected it. it works now.